# How can i use dos batch file to get a list of folders in a folder and convert it into a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, command, dos

How can I use a dos batch file to get a list of folders in a main folder and convert it into a JavaScript array?

I know:

```
set foldersList = dir /b /ad ""
%foldersList% > file.txt
```

Will give me a list of the folders with newline between them, but I don't know how to convert it to something like this:

```
var foldersList = ['name1','name2,..... ]
```

Comment: Once the text file is created, how do you plan to use it? Are you wanting to access the file from a website? Will the file be on a server accessible to the website? Basically, the JavaScript needs to be able to get at the content of the file. How are you going to make that happen?

Comment: a batch file can work with lots of nested escaping, but considering that chrome and node.js can both get a deep folder list, i wonder if a batch file is the best approach...

Comment: you can store raw text inside a comment inside a function in JS, and since you say JS array instead of JSON, you can ship the whole list inside an empty function with one comment: the line-seperated list of files. you can then  `String(fnName).split("*")[1].split("\n")` to get your array of file names. the advantage is you just need to write a static header to the top and a static tail to the raw text list: you need not scrub each line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if your batch file outputted it to a formatted JS include as plain text into the HTTP Dir, and your HTML included it.
For example

```
del "c:\httpdocs\mywebsite\protectedincludes\vars.js"
set foldersList = dir /b /ad ""
%foldersList% > tempfile.txt
echo "var myJsArray=[" > "c:\httpdocs\mywebsite\protectedincludes\vars.js" 2>&1
FOR /f %a in (‘tempfile.txt’) do (
echo "'" > "c:\httpdocs\mywebsite\protectedincludes\vars.js" 2>&1
echo %a > "c:\httpdocs\mywebsite\protectedincludes\vars.js" 2>&1
echo "'," > "c:\httpdocs\mywebsite\protectedincludes\vars.js" 2>&1
)
echo "];" > "c:\httpdocs\mywebsite\protectedincludes\vars.js" 2>&1
```

and then on your webpage you can easily include it:

```
<html>
<script src="protectedIncludes/vars.js"></script>
<script> Do something with myJsArray </script>
```

Something along these lines anyway. Bedtime for me now though. 
edit. couple of typos.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much for the fast answer, i will check it soon and let you know if it did the job :)

Comment: Alright, with some modifications it worked great, thanks again TechnicalChaos :)